# Highchart drillup issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to drill up using my own button but having difficulties.

[JSfiddle with multi drilldown](http://jsfiddle.net/2tjPp/)

```
$( "#backbtn" ).click(function(e) {          
    setChartC(name, categories, data, '', 1);          
    alert(chartC.xAxis[0]);
});
```

I have levels, how can I access the `drilldown.level`?

```
exporting: {
         enabled: true,
         buttons: {
            customButton: {
                text: 'Go Back',
                onclick: function () {
                        var drilldown = chartC.drilldown;

                        alert(chartC.level);
                }
            }
        }
```

Cant seem to access the level as i got drill down. is there any way I can access the `level`

Comment: Have you considered using `drilldown.js` module for Highcharts? See [examples](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#drilldown). It's much easier than building your own drilldown logic. And it comes with built-in button for a drillup action :)

Comment: yes, but the series and data structure is different?

Comment: The structure is up to you, I think. I mean, in `drilldown.js` Highcharts require the same structure for the main series, and all drilldown series.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native Highcharts back button. You can see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ed3ob9au/) (link author [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153403/drilldown-multiple-levels-highchart#comment51802320_23154288)).

However, if you want to add a custom button, I don't believe that Highcharts have an easy way for that. If you find that I'm wrong, please correct me.

So, to add a custom back button, you need to track what is the current chart that you are showing. Knowing what is the current, you could look into a dictionary to find which level it is. To get the current chart, you can track the click events:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function () {
                    console.log("I'm at: " + this.drilldown.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding the custom back button, look this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75kd1nwv/).

Add this HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="backbtn" value="Back">
```

And this JS:

```
$("#backbtn").click(function(e) {   
    setChart(name, categories, data);
});
```

Since the variables `name`, `categories` and `data` were defined with the values of the top-level chart, clicking in this button will restore to the top-level.

If you create a tree object with all charts and their name/categories/data info, and if you know the current chart, you can set the Chart with its parent data to implement the custom back button.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I am trying to do but cant seem to get the drilldown.level? it goes back to beginning state.

Comment: You could create a level property, but unfortunately, you would still need to track the object separately. I can't see an easier way right now.

Comment: would it be possible to show an exampel in Jfiddel?

Comment: To add button in Highcharts, use.. `chart.renderer.button()` ;) Not part of the API, but see [source code](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/143cb9889e11648cd99b1cad4acdb102b2010575/js/parts/SvgRenderer.js#L1678). For example `chart.renderer.button("Drillup", 100, 100, function() { console.log("test"); });`

Comment: @Pawel Fus: where do we put the code?  'chart.renderer.button()'
e.g: which event?

Comment: In drilldown/click event. Still, I would suggest to use `drilldown.js` - you will save a lot of time.