# HighCharts Drill Down multiple series , how to get drill down on second item on drill down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I see a few examples on multiple series downs , but I don't see an example on how to get a third level drill down on the second item on the second drill down series.

for [example](http://jsfiddle.net/NULTY/1200/).

```
        drilldown: {
           name: 'MSIE versions',
           categories: ['MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
           level: 1, 
           data: [{
               y: 33.06,
               drilldown: {
                   level: 2,
                   name: 'drilldown next level',
                   categories: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                   data: [23,54,47],
                   color: colors[0]
               }
           }, 10.85, 7.35, 2.41],
           color:
```

After MSIE , I haven't seen an example where the second item in the series (MSIE 6.0) is setup to go to the 3rd level. I've only seen examples where the first item (MSIE 8.0). Is there a way to setup the second or third item to go to the 3rd level ?

Comment: you can do it similarly as for (MSIE 8.0). May it Help! [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/edmkfcht/#&togetherjs=mLx7DDJaFH)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drilldown multiple levels Highchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153403/drilldown-multiple-levels-highchart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
 var chart;
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
                categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera'],
                name = 'Browser brands',
                level = 0,
                data = [{
                    y: 55.11,
                    color: colors[0],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'MSIE versions',
                        categories: ['MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
                        level: 1,
                        data: [{
                            y: 33.06,
                            drilldown: {
                                level: 2,
                                name: 'drilldown next level2',
                                categories: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                                data: [23, 54, 47],
                                color: colors[0]
                            }
                        }, {
                            y: 10.85,
                            drilldown: {
                                level: 2,
                                name: 'drilldown next level2',
                                categories: ['e', 'f', 'g'],
                                data: [23, 54, 47],
                                color: colors[0]
                            }
                            }, {
                                y: 7.35,
                                drilldown: {
                                    level: 2,
                                    name: 'drilldown next level2',
                                    categories: ['h', 'i', 'j'],
                                    data: [78, 11, 90],
                                    color: colors[0]
                                }
                        }, {
                            y: 2.41,
                            drilldown: {
                                level: 2,
                                name: 'drilldown next level2',
                                categories: ['k', 'l', 'm'],
                                data: [45, 12, 67],
                                color: colors[0]
                            }
                        }],
                        color: colors[0]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 21.63,
                    color: colors[1],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Firefox versions',
                        categories: ['Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 2.0'],
                        data: [13.52, 5.43, 1.58, 0.83, 0.20],
                        color: colors[1]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 11.94,
                    color: colors[2],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Chrome versions',
                        categories: ['Chrome 10.0', 'Chrome 11.0', 'Chrome 8.0', 'Chrome 9.0', 'Chrome 12.0',
                            'Chrome 6.0', 'Chrome 5.0', 'Chrome 7.0'],
                        data: [9.91, 0.50, 0.36, 0.32, 0.22, 0.19, 0.12, 0.12],
                        color: colors[2]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 7.15,
                    color: colors[3],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Safari versions',
                        categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
                            'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 41'],
                        data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
                        color: colors[3]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 2.14,
                    color: colors[4],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Opera versions',
                        categories: ['Opera 11.x', 'Opera 10.x', 'Opera 9.x'],
                        data: [1.65, 0.37, 0.12],
                        color: colors[4]
                    }
                }];

            function setChart(name, categories, data, color, level) {
                chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
                chart.series[0].remove();


                chart.addSeries({
                    name: name,
                    data: data,
                    level: level,
                    color: color || 'white'
                });
            }

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Click again to view brands.'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: categories
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Total percent market share'
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                click: function () {

                                    var drilldown = this.drilldown;
                                    if (drilldown) { // drill down

                                        this.series.chart.setTitle({
                                            text: drilldown.name
                                        });

                                        setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data, drilldown.color, drilldown.level);
                                    } else { // restore
                                        setChart(name, categories, data, null, level);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: colors[0],
                            style: {
                                fontWeight: 'bold'
                            },
                            formatter: function () {
                                return this.y + '%';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        var point = this.point, s = '';

                        switch (this.series.options.level) {
                            case 0:
                                s = 'LEVEL ONE<br/>';
                                s += ' INSTRUCTIONS HERE 111';
                                break;

                            case 1:
                                s = 'LEVEL TWO INSTRUCTIONS HERE <br/>';
                                s += ' INSTRUCTIONS HERE 222';
                                break;

                            case 2:
                                s = 'LEVEL THREE INSTRUCTIONS HERE<br/>';
                                s += 'INSTRUCTIONS HERE 333';
                                break;
                        }
                        return s;
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: name,
                    level: level,
                    data: data,
                    color: 'white'
                }],
                exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            });


        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500px"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rony,  works great, I was was getting more complicated then I needed to be.